# Inject dependencies into ServletContextListener using HK2 in Jersey

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2, servletcontextlistener

In order to initialize the application at startup, I extended `ServletContextListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ... initialization code here
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

Now I want to extract the initialization logic into a standalone `StartupManager` class, and delegate to this class from `MyServletContextListener`:

```
public class StartupManager {

    public void performStartup() {
        ... initialization code here
    }
}
```

I tried to inject `StartupManager` into `ServletContextListener` by simply adding `@Inject` annotation:

```
@WebListener
public class MyServletContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    @Inject StartupManager mStartupManager;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        mStartupManager.performStartup();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

This did not work - the reference is null when `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent )` is called.

Then I thought that I might have to register a binder:

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        register(new DependencyInjectionBinder());
    }
}

public class DependencyInjectionBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StartupManager.class).to(StartupManager.class);
    }
}
```

This did not work either.

My question is how can I perform injection of dependencies into `ServletContextListener`? Preferably constructor injection, but field injection will also be alright.

Comment: You can't. The servlet listener goes through a completely separate system from Jersey. Maybe look into using Jersey's [ApplicationEventListener](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e15999) instead of the servlet listener

Comment: @peeskillet, it works. Need to skip the first `ApplicationEvent` of type `INITIALIZATION_START` and then the dependencies are injected. However, the documentation you referenced states: `Jersey monitoring support has been released as a beta release in Jersey 2.1 version. As such, the exposed monitoring public APIs and functionality described in this section may change in the future Jersey releases.`. Do you have an idea of how stable this API is today?

Comment: [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.0/docs/)'s been using it to handle Hibernate session management. I'd probably say it's stable enough.

Comment: @peeskillet, great. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: I don't think it's quite possible with HK2, You could do it with Guice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not going to work, as the servlet listener and Jersey are not linked to the same system. As an alternative, you can use Jersey's [Event Listeners](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16058). You can implement an `ApplicationEventListener` where you would be able to initialization and clean up in the same way you would in the servlet listener. You would be able to inject your services into Jersey's listener.